# gitlab get tar of a specific branch via command line

Tags: git, command-line, gitlab

I'm using gitlab. When I go into the interface, on each branch I can download the source code as a zip, tar or whatsoever.

I am making rpm spec files for which I would need the possibility to download the tar ball using command line. since I added my rsa key i can do git clone without problems:

```
git clone http://gitlab/group/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Counting objects: 1885, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (826/826), done.
remote: Total 1885 (delta 1194), reused 1496 (delta 954)
Receiving objects: 100% (1885/1885), 1.30 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1194/1194), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

However doing

```
wget http://gitlab/group/project/repository/archive.zip
```

gets me these errors:

```
Resolving gitlab (gitlab)... 10.1.253.75
Connecting to gitlab (gitlab)|10.1.253.75|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [GitLab 6.2](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/4123c76ec192f08be4d74f4958624c6e87041564) and [issue 5253](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5253), it should be:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/archive
```

But that seems for internal use only, since you cannot know the id of a project as a user (only its name).

Don't forget, as [`shown in ability.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/0c5c1157af07b344350700da97d530184ef055f1/app/models/ability.rb#L43), that downloading an archive is linked to a permission. Make sure you have that "`download_code`" permission set for your project.

Here, it must be a permission issue, because, for instance:

```
wget http://demo.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-recipes/repository/archive.zip
```

That works just fine, and get the content of that project without any issue.

---

However, as the [OP Chris Maes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2082964/chris-maes) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691197/gitlab-get-tar-of-a-specific-branch-via-command-line/22692072#comment34619641_22692072) and mentions in [issue 6645](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6645#issuecomment-38931794), as as illustrated by [`app/models/ability.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/0c5c1157af07b344350700da97d530184ef055f1/app/models/ability.rb#L33):

```
 if project && project.public?
```

... that "`dowload_code`" feature is *only* for public projects.

Comment: as I said; i have put the rsa-key so I can clone without him asking for my username and pwd... but how do I get that ID you are talking about? Now I go in the interface and copy the download url from the "get tar" button

Comment: @ChrisMaes that won't work: the API doesn't support yet accessing a project by its name, only by its id: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4921

Comment: I'm not really using the API (don't know how); so if I'm in command line or in the interface: can I get the project ID? How? so if I have project id, the command "wget http://gitlab/projects/:123/repository/archive.tar" should work? I'm afraid not but don't really understand how to use the API...

Comment: @ChrisMaes no, it would be `wget http://yourGiLabServer/projects/:id/repository/archive`: the only challenge is in finding the id of your project (but I don't see how to get the id of a project when looking around at  http://demo.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-recipes). However, in your case, this must be a permission issue, because `wget http://demo.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-recipes/repository/archive.zip` works just fine for me.

Comment: your analysis is good, tx. But I added my rsa-key to my gitlab account. I can do "git clone http://gitlabserver/..." without issues... strange!

Comment: @ChrisMaes adding the rsa allows GitHub to know who you are, but it isn't enough to grant you all the rights. I guess this is managed at the project administration level.

Comment: off course, but I am administrator myself; I have all the necessary permissions since I can clone and commit... I'll try again tomorrow when I'm at work...

Comment: I tried it again, it works only for "public" projects in gitlab. Whenever I try this with a project that is "internal" or "protected", it doesn't work. I edited my question to show you the exact errors, and to show that i can clone using http.

Comment: @ChrisMaes cloning and getting the archives are two different actions, managed by two different authorization levels (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/0c5c1157af07b344350700da97d530184ef055f1/app/models/ability.rb#L43). There must be in the admin interface of those private repo a way to grant `download_code` right for your user.

Comment: I am the owner of the project... so I am supposed to have the rights to do anything with the code, including dowloading... no?

Comment: @ChrisMaes not sure, I would still double check what default privileges come with ownership. But in general, I would agree with you. Although, when I look at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/0c5c1157af07b344350700da97d530184ef055f1/app/models/ability.rb#L33, I hope this "`download_code`" feature isn't reserved *only* for public projects...

Comment: I opened a question on gitlabhq; they say it is not possible if the project is not public: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6645#issuecomment-38931794

Comment: @ChrisMaes that is *exactly* what I just said in my last comment: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/0c5c1157af07b344350700da97d530184ef055f1/app/models/ability.rb#L33

Comment: @ChrisMaes I have included this conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: ok I'm sorry I over read the last part of your comment. Thanks for your support...

Answer (score 5):

For me the `private_token` and the `sha` or `ref` parameters does not worked together. So, I changed the way, and I tell my private token via a header parameter to the Gitlab API, like this:

```
wget http://{{your_host}}/api/v3/projects/{{project_id}}/repository/archive?sha={{commit_sha}} --header='PRIVATE-TOKEN: {{private_token}}'
```

Comment: In my case it worked for downloading the compressed source-code files from an internal repository. My formulation was `wget https://gitlab.com/<developer>/<project>/-/archive/master/<compressed source code> --header='PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access token>`. I got the full path from the web-based project page (right-clicking on the list of downloadable compressed source codes); and the access token from https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens (in my case I selected read_repository as access choice)

Comment: This solution has worked out also in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083881/5459638, and for me

Comment: This works for me with SaaS Gitlab as of Dec 1st 2019. You can find your Project ID on the Repo home page. I selected `v4` as my API version. I used `?ref=master` instead of `?sha=`

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
curl http://$yourhost:$port/$yourgroup/$yourrepo/repository/archive.zip\?ref\=$yourbranch\&\private_token\=$yourtoken -o newpackage.zip
```

Comment: If you had read the answer you would have found that OP's issue can't be solved because the download feature is supported only for public repositories; OP asked about a non-public repository.

Comment: @MaxLeske OP didn't ask about non-public repo in the question. At any rate, his answer is useful and I don't know where else to have found it.

NOTE: `$yourrepo` is _without_ the `.git` extension

Comment: Our GitLab was upgraded to 8.2. This doesn't work anymore. Anyone have similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

With the newer version of gitlab, you can use

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive?sha=<commit_sha>"
```

You can also pass different archive format, e.g `tar.bz2`

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive.tar.bz2?sha=<commit_sha>"
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't want to have to get the project ID first, but rather use group|org and repository name similar to the Github HTTP API. This is what works for me on 11.9.0-ce.0

Private/Internal Project

```
curl "https://gitlab.yourdomain.com/api/v4/projects/engineering%2Faccount-service/repository/archive?sha=some-branch-name" \
  -H "Private-Token: $GITLAB_TOKEN" \
  -o /tmp/account-service-branch-name.tar.gz
```

Public Project

```
curl "https://gitlab.yourdomain.com/engineering/account-service/repository/archive.tar.gz?ref=some-branch-name" \
  -o /tmp/account-service-branch-name.tar.gz
```

In this example

- "group" is `engineering`
- "repository" is `account-service`

Don't forget the `%2F` between `group` and `repo`

Hope it helps anyone