# Open a file directly from a GitLab private repository

Tags: linux, git, drupal, gitlab, drush

I have a private repository on a GitLab server and using the SSH I can pull a project using git clone.

But I want to run a script on linux command line directly from the server (more specific, a Drupal / Drush .make file)

I tried to run it using the raw file:

```
drush make http://server.com/user/project/raw/master/file.make
```

(for the convenience of non Drupal users let’s say)

```
curl http://server.com/user/project/raw/master/file.make
```

Without success. Of course, it returns me the login page.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does `http://user:password@server.com/user/project/raw/master/file.make`, replacing `user` and `password` with your credentials, work?

Comment: Thank for the help but it doesn't work. Also I would like a solution without exposing my password. (but even if that works it will be really good!)

Comment: You're going to have a tough time accessing files over HTTP without exposing your password. In theory you could use a *client-side* SSL certificate to authenticate, but that's likely a lot of work. I seriously doubt that it's supported by GitLab. You may want to create a dedicated read-only account and use that in your command to limit your exposure.

Comment: http://www.systemseed.com/blog/drush-make-private-git-repository-github

Comment: To be honest my final goal is to grab the .make files from a GitLab server and feed them on a Aegir server so it can create "platforms". But, for the moment, I try the middle linux-steps (as Aegir uses drush commands).

So if I add on the Aegir server an SSL certificate I can verify it on the GitLab and will have a password-less client-to-server communication?

Comment: Only if you manage to get GitLab to rely on client SSL certificates as an authentication method. If GitLab offers something similar to GitHub's API, the link I added above may get you started.

Comment: Man you are awesome! I knew about the tokens, but I didn't try them. Thanks for the guid-inspiration.
GitLab have tokens and an excellent API. [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/README.md#gitlab-api). So if you want to grab a raw file you must do somethink like: http://gitlabserver.com/api/v3/projects/:project-id/repository/raw_blobs/:sha?private_token=:token.

Comment: Glad to see that this helped. Once you've got it working, please consider answering your own question with details about what you needed to do. I don't have a GitLab box handy and don't feel comfortable writing an answer without one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55585/discussion-between-tolis-and-chris).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris)'s valuable help, here is how you can run a script (drupal .make file in my case) from a GitLab server. (Probably it works for GitHub but I didn't test it. Maybe the syntax will be a bit different). (Of course this works for any type of script)

It can be done using the authentication tokens. [Here is the documentation of the GitLab's API](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/README.md) and [here is the GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

For convenient I will use the https://gitlab.com as the example server.

- Go to https://gitlab.com/profile/account and find your "Private token"
- Then print the list of the projects and find the id of your project you are looking for

  `curl https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=<your_private_token>`

  or go there with your browser (a [json viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) will help a lot)
- Then print the list of the files that are on this project and find the id of your file you are looking for

  `curl https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/<project_id>/repository/tree?private_token=<your_private_token>`
- Finally get / run the file!

  `curl https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/<project_id>/repository/raw_blobs/<file_id>?private_token=<your_private_token>`

In case you want to run the script (drupal .make)

`drush make https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/<project_id>/repository/raw_blobs/<file_id>?private_token=<your_private_token> <drupal_folder>`

(If you are here looking for a workflow to integrate GitLab with Aegir .make platforms without using tokens (maybe SSH?) please make a thread and paste here the link.)

**EDIT**

You can get the file without the `project_id` by using the *encoded* project name. For example the `my-user-name/my-project` will become: `my-user-name%2Fmy-project`

Comment: How to access a file in a folder? Is it possible to use a fixed file id? The id changes every time I update the file.

Comment: Sorry @Yong I can't help you as I don't use this method for long time now because it wasn't practical.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out another way to make it work. This is how I did:  `https://gitlab.com/<group_name>/<project_name>/raw/master/<folder>/<file_name>?private_token=<your_key>`

Comment: @Yong doesn't work for me (or rather, only works as long as i also use a cookie session which is already logged in, and the private_token is ignored

Comment: Currently the private token is probably called 'access token'. I got one from https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens and have used it successfully for downloading from a private repository with wget (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31442131/5459638 for the interested ones). By asking for an access token you will need to specify expiry date and purpose (in my case, read_repository)

Comment: I downvoted the answer and @BruceYongLi's because the path to access a file in a folder does not work. I found GitLab very hostile than GitHub, regards cURL, SVN and wget. I'll switch to GitHub and use the old and good SVN.

Answer (score 11):

Update 2018-12-25:

as long as you're not downloading huge files, this should work:

```
curl -s -H "Private-Token: <token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<urlencode("gitlab_username/project_name")>/repository/files/<path/to/file>/raw?ref=<branch_name>"
```

, a real example, downloading the file `/README.md` from the private repository `https://gitlab.com/divinity76/Yur17`, where the web download url is `https://gitlab.com/divinity76/Yur17/raw/master/README.md?inline=false`, is:

```
curl -s -H "Private-Token: afF2s1xgk6xcwXHy3J4C" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/divinity76%2Fyur17/repository/files/README%2Emd/raw?ref=master"
```

take special note of how the `gitlab_username/repo_name` was url-encoded, eg `/` became `%2F` (you can check how your username & repo name is as url-encoded by opening your browser javascript terminal and write `encodeURIComponent("your_username/repo_name");` in the terminal and press enter.)

thanks to `Jonathan Hall` @ gitlab at mg.gitlab.com, and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html , and [tvl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210596/1067003) for helping reach a solution.

---

---

Update 2018-12-11: this method no longer works, now it just serves the login page, with a message saying `need to log in to continue`, even using HTTP 200 OK (shame on them), will update if i find out why ( @XavierStuvw claims it's security concerns related)

---

---

i found a much easier way to do it than @tvl 's answer,

first create an access token with API access here: https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens , 
then do:

`wget --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>' 'https://gitlab.com/<username>/<repo>/raw/master/path/to/file.ext'`

i found the solution [here.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/31470)

Comment: This solution has also worked out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31442131/5459638, and for me

Comment: This no longer works for security concerns - but the API is available and you can just use the `read_repository` scope (no need for the API scope).

Comment: @BLuEGoD yeah doesn't work now :< - werid, TLS certificates are verified before headers are sent so it's probably not a MITM concern, do you know what security concerns they are talking about?

Comment: @hanshenrik see "Improper Enforcement of Token Scope" in https://about.gitlab.com/2018/11/28/security-release-gitlab-11-dot-5-dot-1-released/

Comment: @BLuEGoD thanks for the heads-up, found a new (albeit terrible from a bandwidth point-of-view) way to do it, that is still easier than tvl's answer ^^

Comment: @hanshenrik Regarding your update "Update 2018-12-25" with gitlab-API v4: please add a "/raw" before ?ref=<branch_name>" then you can remove the | jd ... > filename.ext

Comment: For gitlab-API v4 I had to insert <project_id> instead of <urlencode("gitlab_username/project_name")>

Comment: <path/to/file> must also be urlencoded, e.g. . with %2E and / with %2F.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to access a file from private GitLab, you could use the below approach which worked for me:)

*Construct the URL:*

**https://url/api/v4/projects/projectId/repository/files/fileName/raw?ref=master&private_token=Generated_private_token**

---

- url is your Gitlab url ex: **git.lab.com.**
- **/api/v4/projects** is a constant.
- **projectId** is the projectId of your project, which you can find below the name of your project in gitlab.
- **/repository/files** is again a constant.
- **fileName** is the name of the file ex: sagar.txt
- **/raw?ref=** is a constant and the value of ref can be master or any branch which you would like to take the file from. I am retrieving the file from Master.
- **Generated_private_token** should be generated from gitlab, please follow the steps in mentioned in the link : 
  [Generate Private Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)

Comment: Note that file path needs to be url encoded ie. `app/models/key.rb` goes in the url as `app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. GitLab docs suck if you use private GitLab. This one works great. Thanks!

Comment: This returns `{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}` even though the repo exists with all the necessary perms to the token