# Get raw csv data from private Gitlab

Tags: r, csv, gitlab

I want to read a csv file from my private Gitlab repo given by my university into R. I know that you have to use the "Raw" file to read CSV's and I was able to pull it up. Reading a raw csv file from a public GitHub works just fine. I can provide the URL to the file from my private Gitlab:
https://git.cs.slu.edu/courses/fall20/capstone/covid_dashboard/-/raw/master/covid_scrape/data/county_data.csv

However when you click on it, it will have you sign in and only using my credentials. Also, doing

```
read.csv("https://git.cs.slu.edu/courses/fall20/capstone/covid_dashboard/-/raw/master/covid_scrape/data/county_data.csv")
```

will just provide the HTML of the sign in page. I would like to know if there's a way for me to get this data onto R and read from it? Thank you!!

Comment: Does your private gitlab site allow you to create an access token? See more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207644/open-a-file-directly-from-a-gitlab-private-repository/48083881. You're going to need some sort of authentication token to access private files.

Comment: Hi again @MrFlick! Thank you so much the forum you provided was extremely helpful!! Cheers